# Query to Display data if the value is greater than 3 in any of the last 3 months in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I want to filter the value if any month in the last 3 months has the value>=3. See the image i have highlighted which i need in output.

Queries I tried.

```
select Application_Infrastructure,year,month_name,count(ticket_no) as 'CN' from [service_delivery]
where month_num in (MONTH(getdate()),MONTH(getdate())-1,MONTH(getdate())-2,MONTH(getdate())-3)
group by Application_Infrastructure,year,month_name 
having count(ticket_no)>=3
 order by Application_Infrastructure,CN
```

`having count(ticket_no)>=3` is eliminating the value which is less than 3 for that month.

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98p9.png)

Comment: Please show us the query that generates the current results.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What does your data look like before the query you forgot to include in your question (don't use images of data either, provide it as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements). Also, SQL Server 2008 is completely unsupported now; I strongly suggest you prioritise upgrading in the (very) near future.

Comment: i gave that data as an example , query is select Application_Infrastructure,year,month_name,count(ticket_no) as 'CN' from [service_delivery]
where month_num in (MONTH(getdate()),MONTH(getdate())-1,MONTH(getdate())-2,MONTH(getdate())-3)
group by Application_Infrastructure,year,month_name 
having count(ticket_no)>=3
 order by Application_Infrastructure,CN 
                                                                               this eliminate the values which are not greater than 3 , but for me if any month value is greater than 3 whole Application_Infrastructure data has to display.

Comment: [edit] your question @MUHAMMEDTHAYYABSAWOODSYED . The comments are for comments, not for information that should be in your question.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, i have edited the question.

Comment: Since the month is enough to let you filter out the most recent three months of data you must not be planning on having more than one year worth of data in the table. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window `max()` to in a subquery compute the maximum count per `application_infrastructure` over the 3 months, and filter by that in the outer query.

```
select *
from (
    select 
        application_infrastructure, 
        year,
        month_name,
        count(ticket_no) cn,
        max(count(ticket_no)) over(partition by application_infrastructure) max_cn
    from service_delivery
    where datefromparts(year, month_num, 1) 
        >= dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
    group by application_infrastructure, year, month_num, month_name
) t
where max_cn <= 3
order by application_infrastructure, cn
```

Note that I rewrote your `where` clause so it properly and more efficiently filters on the last 3 months.

Comment: Now i am getting error of 'datefromparts' is not a recognized built-in function name. may be this is due to SQL Server 2008